# jquery serialize not getting the filled values

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

I want to serialize data of a form using jquery.

```
$('#genaricLogin').click(function () {

            //form id   
        console.log( $("#genaricLoginForm").serialize());
    });
```

but it only writes the names of input fields in console not the field values.

```
email=&password=
```

I am using same function for two other forms on the same page working fine.

```
$('#singupHost').click(function () {


    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    // add spinner to button
    $(this).html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Processing...`
    );

    axios.post('dinesignup' , $("#signup-host-ajax").serialize())
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            if($.isEmptyObject(response.data.error)){

                $(".alert-danger").css('display','none');
                window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

            }else{

                $(".alert-danger").css('display','block');
                $(".alert-danger").html(response.data.error);
                $('#singupHost').prop("disabled", false);

                $('#singupHost').html(
                    `Sign up me`
                );
            }
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(function () {
            // always executed
        });
});
```

basically I am using Axios request to send data.

Comment: Are there values present in the form input fields? Since `email=&password=` would be the result of serializing an unfilled form. Alternatively you could have two forms with the same *id* on the page. Normally an *id* has to be unique, so if you have multiple forms with the *id* "genaricLogin" `$("#genaricLoginForm").serialize()` will only returned a serialized version of the first one it encounters.

Comment: yes, you are right its shows warning in the console.

Comment: but I didn't set two forms same id

Comment: Just a general point: if you're using jQuery, it comes with $.ajax built in. So why use axios? You already have an AJAX library available. Why load your page up with another one??

Comment: Anyway in order to understand your problem better, you should show us the related HTML form. Also, where are you seeing these values in the console exactly? In your code I can only see you logging the server response, not the serialised form data.